# overflow:auto on child of overflow:hidden div?

Tags: css

I have a div that must be set to overflow:hidden, and I want one of its child divs to scroll through content; however, no matter how I play with the overflow on the child, it won't scroll. How can I override the inheritance?

Answer (score 8):

You likely have not specified a height on the inner div.

Without height on the div its height will be the height of its content and hence it will never need to scroll.  Of course with it being contained in an outer div that does have height and overflow:hidden its content disappears under the border of the outer div.